# Array to String in Laravel Ajax Data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-controller

I am sending my data to a controller by Ajax, but on the back-end, I'm getting `Array to string conversion.`

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function updateimages(Request $request){
    $updateDetails=array(
        'image_alt' => $request->get('image_alt')
    );

    $updateIds=array(
        'id' => $request->get('id')
    );

    $images = DB::table('photos')
        ->where([$updateIds])
        ->update([$updateDetails]);

    return response()->json(['updated' => $images], 200);
}
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".SaveImage").on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();

          var idmess= [];
          $(".photohe").each(function(){
            idmess.push($(this).val());
          });

          var image_alt= [];
          $(".image_alt").each(function(){
            image_alt.push($(this).val());
          });

          console.log(idmess);
          console.log(image_alt);
          $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('admin/savemulti') }}',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: "JSON",
              data: {
                  "id": idmess,
                  "image_alt": image_alt,
                  "_method": 'POST',
                  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              },
              success:function(data) {
                var message = "Image Updated successfully!"
                $('.saved').append(message);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

**Here is how my controller dd gets the data:**

```
array:4 [
  "id" => array:2 [
    0 => "1045"
    1 => "1046"
  ]
  "image_alt" => array:2 [
    0 => "mage 1"
    1 => "image 2"
  ]
  "_method" => "POST"
  "_token" => "SParC5rwYy0KLLhwa0km7fcZvodSqrzhvyqZUqk3"
]
```

It's supposed to update it like:

```
1045 = mage 1
1046 = image 2
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting array to string conversion error ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do multiple updates with the way you are doing in above code. You are adding of ids and data to be updated separately in two arrays.

You have to change your code something like this.

```
public function updateimages(Request $request){
    $ids = $request->get('id');
    $updateImages = $request->get('image_alt');

    foreach($ids as $key => $value){
        DB::table('photos')
          ->where('id',$value)
          ->update(['image_alt'=>$updateImages[$key]]);
    }

    return DB::table('photos')->whereIn('id',ids)->get();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this now `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `photos` set `0` = mage 1 where `id` = 1045)`

Comment: I think it's getting `0` from array `0 => 1045` my console return this as front-end results `(2) […]
​
0: "1045"
​
1: "1046"
​
(2) […]
​
0: "mage 1"
​
1: "image 2"`

Comment: @mafortis With $key=>$value it should work I think, let me see

Comment: @mafortis My bad, while updating we have to give column name and value, i'd missed that. Now try the updated one.